# Button anchor property does not work on autoscroll panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, anchor

I have an autoscroll panel with a button on it, the problem is that anchor property position of this button is not working as this property is set to 'Bottom and right' and always overlab     with panel's buttom.
please how do I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is remarked by MSDN. You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll.aspx)

Further the only work around I could think of is:

1. Set Anchor property of the button to Left and Top for both scrollbars to be displayed

But if you still are going to set the Anchor properties to Bottom And Right then I believe that the button will always show clipped on the top if the panel's size is smaller than the button's.

So if you still want to maintain the Bottom-Right positioning of the button, I suggest you use the TableLayoutPanel which is good for layout purposes and preserves positioning of the controls in it.